# What are the major omissions in mruby compared to MRI?

Tags: ruby, mruby

I'm quite interested in the [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby) project, but have had no luck in finding a summarization of the major omissions in mruby compared to other, more complete Ruby implementations (most importantly, MRI).

The README in the project says that mruby implements "part of" the [ISO standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579) for Ruby, but doesn't go into detail about which features are omitted.

Does anyone know of a list of such omissions, or is anyone familiar enough with the implementation to summarize?

Answer (score 5):

So I haven't read the source closely, but after having built mruby and run the interpreter a bit, I found that the following things were missing (by no means is this a complete list, nor do I know whether these are intentional omissions or just things that haven't been written yet):

- backticks
- `eval`
- `String#scan`
- `(instance|module|class)_eval` with `String` arguments
- `Module.constants`
- `Regexp`
- `Process`
- `Bignum`
- `IO`, `File`, and `Dir`
- `Encoding`
- `Thread` and `Mutex`
- `Marshal`

If anyone has a more complete list, or knows the details as to whether these bits are just not *yet* implemented or are intentionally omitted, I'd still be curious to know.

Comment: Are these things which have been completely eliminated, or are just going to be pushed out into optional "mrbgems"?

Answer (score 4):

An partial but up-to-date list of differences between Ruby MRI and MRuby can be found at https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/doc/limitations.md.

As of March 2020 these are the listed differences:

- `1/2` gives `Float(0.5)` because mruby does not support Bignum.
- Passing an Array to `puts` results in different output.
- `Kernel.raise` without arguments does not raise the current exception within a rescue clause.
- Fiber execution can't cross C function boundary
- `Array` does not support instance variables
- No method visibility (`public`/`private`/`protected`) is supported.
- `defined?` is missing
- Aliasing a global variable works in CRuby but is not part of the ISO standard.
- An operator can't be overwritten by the user.
- `Kernel#binding` is not supported.
- Keyword arguments splats (`def foo(a, b, **k)`) are parsed in a different way.
- Arguments cannot default to other destructed arguments (`def foo(a, (b,c), d=b)` is not valid).
- Any redefinition of the `nil?` metho is ignored in conditional expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the so called mrbgems (https://github.com/mruby/mruby/tree/master/mrbgems). Some of your missing features (i.e. RegExp, eval, File) are available as an additional GEM.

Answer (score 1):

I just run the simple code clip with mruby and got a different result from MRI.

```
class Fixnum
  def +(b)
    self * b
  end
end
puts 3+4
```

mruby outputs 7 while MRI outputs 12

Comment: Are 3 and 4 a Fixnums? Are classes open? This example by itself tells us very little.

Comment: This is the correct behaviour. See mruby limitations here: https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/doc/limitations.md#operator-modification